# How to paste text from chrome extension into a web page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want my extension to paste a saved text (from its popup) when user click on it into current web page (text box or text area) , how i can do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [chrome.contextMenus](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html) API.

Comment: i don't need to use context menus in my extension , i need a method to past saved text into web page when user click on the popup.

Comment: I'm suggesting that when a user triggers a contextMenu you insert the text from the popup.